# Go language: Type XXX is not an expression

Tags: go, slice

I have written a function:

```
func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    type matrix [][]uint8 

    for i := 0; i < dx; i++ { // fills up the matrix with z's in their right places.
        for j := 0; j < dy; j++ {
            matrix[i][j] = Z(i,j)
        }
    }

    return matrix
}
```

that is supposed to fill up a matrix with z values for each x and y value and return it. As I want to have different dimensions for the matrix depending of parameters to the Pic function, I create a slice i line 2. Then in my for loops i fill the matrix up.

I get an error upon running this code: `type matrix is not an expression` for the `matrix[i][j] = Z(i,j)` line. What am I doing wrong? Should matrix[i][j] evaluate to an expression? Why should it, when I want to put something there (it's empty/non-existent now!) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can use `var matrix [][]uint8`, I'd recommend using the built-in `make` function since you know the desired lengths—`dx` for the outer slice and `dy` for the inner slice. The [Two-dimensional slices](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#two_dimensional_slices) section of [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) gives an example of using `make` to allocate a two-dimensional slice. Below is an example for your `Pic` function.

```
func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    matrix := make([][]uint8, dx)

    for i := 0; i < dx; i++ {
        matrix[i] = make([]uint8, dy)
        for j := 0; j < dy; j++ {
            matrix[i][j] = Z(i, j)
        }
    }
    return matrix
}
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You're declaring `matrix` as a type, but using it as a variable.

try:

```
var matrix [][]uint8
```